# How can I make my page content begin below my master page content?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I want to make a home page but when I enter content into the page, it goes above my navigation menu and logo which are in my master page, how can I make it so the content of the page will start below the content of the master page?

master page code:(navigation menu and logo)

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title>Eliyahu's Website</title>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">    
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>

<body>   
<header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="pictures/logo.png" />
        </div>

        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="HomePage.aspx">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="GalleryPage.aspx">GALLERY</a></li>
            <li><a href="AboutPage.aspx">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="RegistrationPage.aspx">REGISTRATION</a></li>
            <li><a href="ContactUsPage.aspx">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>     
</header>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

home page code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HomePage.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="EliyahuWeb.HomePage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" 
runat="server"
<div class="articletitle">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

how it looks like:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvVwU.png)

Comment: can you add code to the `articletitle` class?

Comment: @Radu what do you mean by adding code to the class? like styling it in css? if so than I can, but then it ruins the content from the master page, for example if I add a margin-top then the menu and the logo move down with content inside the div in the home page code.

Comment: no, i meant if you can show us the code from the `articletitle` class

Comment: @Radu don't really understand what you mean by that, I'm pretty new to coding, could you please give me an example?

Comment: I mean that you should add the code from the the `articletitle` class to your question so we can actually see how the styling is, showing us the markup won't help us solve your problem